# When debuginfo rpm is generated?

Tags: rpm

I have a series of RPM spec files and no debuginfo directive set in them. When I run rpmbuild, some packages generate a debuginfo rpm, some do not. What is the criteria used by rpm to decide if a debuginfo is generated? It seems to me that:

- only arch packages generate debuginfo (noarch packages do not)
- only main package in spec generates debuginfo (subpackages do not)

Someone can confirm if these rules are valid and if there are any others?

I have redhat-rpm-config installed, what is a prerequisite to generate debuginfo packages, according to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Debuginfo?rd=Packaging/Debuginfo.

Comment: If what you're really wanting to know is 'why isn't my debug package being build', then you might also check for (wrongly) commented entries like the following:
`#%define debug_package 1`
That looks like a comment, but is not quite. Struck me once; I wrote about it at http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2014/08/building-rpm-debuginfo-package-not.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to generate debuginfo RPMs, the directive `%debug_package` needs to be added to the .spec file (usually, after all package and sub-package definitions and before the `%prep` section, **surrounded by empty lines**).

reference: https://trac.netlabs.org/rpm/wiki/RpmHowToPackagers#Generatingdebuginfopackages

another good blog: https://distracted-it.blogspot.com/2014/08/building-rpm-debuginfo-package-not.html

Answer (score 1):

`%debug_package` has to be included in `.spec` file. I used to write it before 
`%prep` stage. Also, `__debug_package` macro has to be 1.

Comment: how do you set __debug_package macro?

Comment: you dont need to set up __debug_package macro has to be 1. Only setting %debug_package has to be included in .spec file will work.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for 2022.

Debuginfo is automatically generated for binary (architecture is **not** `noarch`) packages, unless disabled with the following:

```
%global debug_package %{nil}
```

Reference https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Debuginfo/#_missing_debuginfo_packages

> It is normal for noarch package builds to not produce a debuginfo
> package. If it’s missing in other cases (where it has not been
> explicitly disabled), something’s wrong. One such case is a
> [missing %build section](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/192422) with some rpmbuild versions.